# Adjusting the rounded cornors of a scope bar in an UISearchController bar

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchcontroller

I have the colors all set the way I want them with this:

```
// Scope bar appearance
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But I still get the white color coming through and NOT being rounded.

See image:

[image]

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I do NOT want the white color as a non rounded edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you AppDelegate add this code at the top

```
    @interface UISegmentedControl (Appearance)

- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;


@end

@implementation UISegmentedControl (Appearance)

- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}


@end
```

And then you can add this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setCornerRadius:5];
```

Comment: I have this but its not working in my ios 8 instance

Comment: I have your code directly under my code from my post. It fails on isMemberOfClass

Comment: and my for is:  for (id subview in self.searchController.searchBar.subviews)

Comment: Yes it is in my viewDidLoad which is a view controller that contains a property for UISearchController

Comment: The for loop has one view as a subview: it is UIView

Comment: @chris I edit my answer and I have try that on sample I hope this will fix for you

Comment: I will test. Upgrading iphone to ios 9 and xcode to 7 and will mark as such when done

Comment: You cant try on the current version also

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
segmentContrl.layer.borderColor = <Set_Your_Color>;
segmentContrl.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5; // You might have to adjust this
segmentContrl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f; // You might have to adjust this
```

Comment: Somehow using the above first answer to grab the subview this puts a border around the whole search bar controller and not the scope bar

Answer (score 0):

try calling below code after setting cornerRadius.

```
segmentContrl.clipsToBounds = true
```